# General programming -- change the variable name or just the display name?

Tags: coding-style

I am working on project that is near completion that handles a business' client information. Amongst the plethora of variables, there are: `main_phone` `cell_phone` and `office_phone` to store various phone numbers of a client. These variables are used all over the project.

The client has asked that we display them as `Phone 1` `Phone 2` and `Phone 3` instead of `Main Phone` `Cell Phone` and `Home Phone`. Their reasons for wanting this change are reasonable.

My question is, would you comb the whole project and change all the variable names (many locations across the project) or simply change how the variable is displayed to the user (one location), and not the underlying variable name itself?

I feel like the latter option is poor style since the variable name no longer explain the data stored within that variable.

Your thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly? I would replace three variables: `main_phone`, `cell_phone` and `office_phone` with one: `phones` of array type. Since the phones are indistinguishable, why keep three distinct variables? Just call `phones[0]`, `phones[1]`, etc. This is also a better design when relational databases are taken into account.

Another benefit is the ability to seamlessly add fourth phone if it ever becomes a requirement.

For the future consider wrapping `phones` array into `Phones` object/structure. Better encapsulation will prevent such massive changes required when requirements change (see: [shotgun surgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery)).

If you can't afford to perform such a huge refactoring, you should change the names to reflect the meaning. If you are using statically typed language, this is fairly simple and safe. Otherwise clever regular expression should do the trick.

Comment: Good call -- at the design phase, it seemed fairly logical that there would only be 3 numbers - main, cell, and office.

Comment: When designing systems, the only numbers you should ever support are zero, one, and N. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule

Answer (score 2):

The requirement change calls for a list of phone numbers so I would actually refactor the code into a collection of phone numbers rather than individual fields. Then, when the customer changes the requirements again, you can very simply add a phone number type... You can add more phone numbers, remove them etc. The code related to phone numbers would become quite maintainable. (I would have suggested a using collection of phone numbers with a phone type attribute in the first place, exactly to deal with these types of scenarios.)

Also, the process you're describing is called refactoring and depending on your language and IDE there are features and/or plug-ins that aid in the process. Many modern IDEs have basic refactoring such as `Rename` built in (Eclipse, Idea, Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the variable name if I had the time to completely test my project.

The latter option will always be a poor subsitute, and use it if you don't have to fix it and test your project completely.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is pure contextual question, if budget supports, combing entire project is good, because it gives clear relationship between front end and code. Otherwise just changing names should be enough. Good programmers can easily relate display text with corresponding backend code on code walk through and simple economical change.

Answer (score 0):

No I wouldn't change them. In a couple of months time they are going to say something like can you order the phones, work, mobile, home in the Phone1,Phone2, Phone3 variables, unless of course you are going to stick them up for the amount of work that would be because you don't have a collection of phones...

Create a noddy class / struct with an array of names (possibly even populated from a resource), then set the displaynames from that, it will sart getting you where you need to be, and will only be a trivial amount of extra work compared to finding every display caption and changing it.

Don't forget things like validation. "Home phone cannot be blank", when it's now called Phone3 will irritate people.

It's a good learner this one, bet "you" won't make this mistake again.